# Getting error in mql5 code while converting to from pinescript 5

Tags: mql5

This is pine script 5 function,

```
rngfilt(x, r) =>
    rngfilt = x
    rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r : 
       x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
    rngfilt
filt = rngfilt(source, smrng)
```

when i tried to convert this code to mql5, i am not able to understand what i am doing wrong.
here is what i did

```
double RangeFilter(double x, double r)
{
    static double rngfilt = 0.0;
    //rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r : x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
        
    if (x > iClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,x))
    {
     /*   if (x - r < xiClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,x) - rngfilt)
            rngfilt = xiClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,x) - rngfilt;
        else
            rngfilt = x - r; */
    }
    else
    {
        if (x + r > xiClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,x) + rngfilt)
            rngfilt = xiClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,x) + rngfilt;
        else
            rngfilt = x + r;
    }

    return rngfilt;
}
```

please help me with this

i want to my code to be corrected please